# New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : A task was canceled

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template

I created the ARM templates for various azure resources like SQL, service bus, key vault, storage, log analytics and virtual machines etc.… And configured the CI and CD with power shell task in VSTS. It’s working fine few days ago, but suddenly I am getting the issue as New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : A task was canceled.
[image]
The above issue occurred even I run the release with local agent and hosted agent also.
Before posting question here i read so many blogs. but those are not helpful to resolve my issue.

[New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : A task was canceled.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102260/new-azurermresourcegroupdeployment-a-task-was-canc.html)

[New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment fails with "Task was cancelled" when too many Microsoft.Resources/deployments in the resource group](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2283)

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve the above issue but the issue occurs randomly.

Comment: What's the result if you deploy it manually on your machine? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Add system.debug variable to release definitioni and set it to true)

Comment: When I run the same PowerShell script from my local machine, it's deployed all azure resources into azure cloud successfully with out any errors. but when I run the same PowerShell script through the VSTS release definition I am getting the above error randomly. This is the OneDrive link for release logs https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CgZJTsn-B07s0ZUH0SQ

Comment: Is there error in the related resource group in Azure? (Azure portal >Resource  group>Select the resource group > Deployments.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, I checked in Deployments of Resource Group but in that there no error or deployment failure.

Comment: You said that getting the error randomly, what's the result if you deploy it manually many times? Try to create a new resource group and try again.

Comment: There are no issues whenever I deploy it manually multiple times from local machine. but the issue occurred randomly, whenever I created release in VSTS for deploying the azure resources.

Comment: What's the result if you try it with a new resource group?

Comment: All resources are created successfully with out any issues in new resource group.

Comment: What's the result if you delete the history of deployment in azure?